# Facebook Login integration into Parse.com App

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to implement a Facebook login option in my App. I followed all the instructions on the Parse website and on the Facebook developer page. I added the frameworks, modified the plist file and added the proper code but when I launch the App I get this exception:

```
2015-07-14 17:50:08.939 ########[35815:2144465] -[ParseManager coreManager]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9cdadad720
2015-07-14 17:50:08.953 ########[35815:2144465] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ParseManager coreManager]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9cdadad720'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3cdc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a066bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3d50ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a32b13c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a32acd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   ########                          0x0000000105c822f0 +[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:] + 151
6   ########                          0x0000000105954c6c -[SMAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1132
7   UIKit                               0x00000001088ef748 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 240
8   UIKit                               0x00000001088f0357 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2540
9   UIKit                               0x00000001088f319e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
10  UIKit                               0x00000001088f2095 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
11  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010be2b5e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a30141c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2f7165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2f6f25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a2f6366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
16  UIKit                               0x00000001088f1b02 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
17  UIKit                               0x00000001088f48c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
18  ########                          0x00000001059c4a9f main + 111
19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a918145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

These are the Frameworks and libraries I actually have on my project:
[image]

The weird thing is that if I create a new project from zero I have no problems at all and the login works correctly.

Edit: I'm still trying to solve this issue. I managed to launch the App without errors by changing the `PFFacebookUtils` initialization code from`[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];` to `[PFFacebookUtils initialize];` but then if I try to login through a button with the code `[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:nil block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {}`another exception appears `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You must initialize PFFacebookUtils with a call to +initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions'`

I'm adding the code I'm using as suggested:

In my `AppDelegate.m`

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

// PARSE
[Parse setApplicationId: SMParseApplicationId
              clientKey: SMParseClientId];

// FACEBOOK
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];


[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
//*****

// GOOGLE MAP API
[GMSServices provideAPIKey: SMGoolgeMapApiKey];
//*****

return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

Comment: Have you added your FacebookAppID and FacebookDisplayName as well as the URL types **correctly** in your .plist?

Comment: Yes I did. I did it more than once to be sure that all was ok.

Comment: I suggest you post all relevant code to Fb login so that we can see what is incorrect or missing.

Comment: @Diego Did you find solution to this?

Comment: No..the PFFacebookUtils initialization always fails and I get the exception. I tried looking for that ParseManager object and that coreManager method the exception is talking about but I can't find them anywhere in my project..Honestly I don't know what to do..I will give up on this.

Answer (score 6):

I've went through this same struggle and tried many different ways to go about setting up Parse with Facebook Login. I have to say though, I have no experience with Obj-C, but here is my working Swift Parse w/ Facebook Login app that I hope can give you some insight.

In my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.setApplicationId("ID", clientKey:"KEY")
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)


    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}


func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

In my `LoginViewController.swift`:

```
//My custom storyboard button
    @IBAction func fbLogin(sender: AnyObject) {

    var permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                self.facebookSignUp(user)
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSuccessful", sender: self)
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        moveToNextView() //Segue to next ViewController
    }
}


func facebookSignUp(user: PFUser) -> Void{
    var request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    var userID:String

    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            user["fullName"] = result["name"]
            var facebookUserID = result["id"] as! String
            user["facebookUserID"] = facebookUserID

            user.save()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSuccessful", sender: self)

        } else {
            println(error)
            PFUser.logOut()
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

There has been a bug in the Parse SDK, [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1462780714012820/) is the bug report with the following answer to fix it.

1) Go to PFFacebookUtils.h

2) change:

```
(void)initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

to:

```
(void)initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:(PF_NULLABLE NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

However, Parse did release a newer version of their SDK (v1.7.2), which should resolve the problem. Please check what SDK you are using.

Comment: I was aware of that bug, in fact the Parse SDK version I'm using it's correct and does have the right line in the PFFacebookUtils.h file.